# I'd like for this to be a word. Why isn't it?

Tags: english, written-language

I am a high school student with a question, and I am not entirely sure this is the right place to voice it. I often encounter situations where I want to use a word to describe a specific situation I'm writing about and then discover I have actually just made the word up.

For example, and this is one I'm particularly upset about, in wanting to say that something that was once abnormal is now expected, I created the word *deanomalize*. The word is created by adding *-ize* to indicate that *anomaly* is being changed, and *de-* to say that it's no longer an anomaly.

To start, if this was hypothetically real, is it even morphologically correct? And if it is, is there a way to introduce the word into actuality?

Comment: As a fellow high school student, I sympathize with your desire to ask linguistics people a fun question, but unfortunately, this question is outside the scope of this site and will probably be closed. “Deanamolize” is a wonderful coinage, but unfortunately this site’s members won’t have much advice about to turn it into an established word. Also, your idea of being “morphological correct” stands in opposition to descriptivism (a super important principle of linguistics).

Comment: I think the core of the question ("how do new words enter a language") is pretty clearly linguistics. Before voting to close as off-topic, I'd consider editing the question to reflect this spirit instead (or closing as a duplicate, if one exists).

Comment: Okay, I submitted an edit myself (not high enough rep, which is why I didn't want to in the first place). I'm a little embarrassed because one might argue that I reworded the question for my answer to make more sense, which would be true. But I'm still hoping that the question merits being on the site. I did a quick search and frankly I was shocked that something like this hadn't already existed on the site -- it's one of the things that linguists are taught on day 1 but horribly misunderstood by the general public.

Comment: Surely it should be deanomalize, right?

Comment: Erm, what's wrong with "normalize"? That's what people use to mean "something that was once abnormal is now expected," and as a bonus, it's an already established word.

Comment: I think the wording might be putting people off, but I think it's a fine question. Essentially, how do neologisms work? The answer is simple. People coin a word, others use it. After a while, the community at large deems it acceptable. It's as simple as that. Be careful, though. Since you're in school, your instructors will scrutinize your work to make sure you know how to use what's available. If you must coin a word, it might be a good idea to qualify your usage, such as saying, "This process could reasonably be called *deanomalization*, though such a word has yet to be coined."

Comment: Also, I'm getting waayyyy out of topic, but few ideas are novel enough that they warrant their own newly minted words.  Generally your writing will be *better* if you avoid them.  See: https://xkcd.com/483/

Comment: @GrahamH. ‘Morphologically correct’ is fine – it just means the word was derived according to the rules that govern derivational morphology in English. In this case, that adding _de-_ to a verbal stem to indicate the reverse of the base verb’s meaning is valid (it is); and that removing the abstract noun marker _-y_ from a noun and adding _-ise_ to form a verb meaning ‘turn into [noun]’ is valid (it is). Had they instead added the _-ise_ straight on without removing _-y_ (_*deanomalyise_), that would have been morphologically invalid.

Comment: @fish I agree that the question should be edited to be more clearly about linguistics, but your edit went too far and removed too much of the question, including some of the linguistic aspects of it, so I’ve voted to reject it. (Another issue is that there are many ‘what is a word?’ questions here already, and this might well be considered a duplicate of one or more of them.)

Comment: @Janus In light of your previous comment discussing the morphological aspect of the question, I'd agree that the edit is not obviously correct. But this doesn't stop the current question from being low-quality -- it contains too much unnecessary detail, and it's unfocused (clearly, since you and I interpreted the main question differently). I'd appreciate if you could clean it up somewhat.

Comment: @fish I agree – unfortunately, while there is a pending edit suggestion for review, it’s not possible to make further edits. Once your edit suggestion has been completed (approved or rejected), I or someone else can make further edits.

Comment: Also, based on a quick skim, while I agree there are many "what is a word" questions, these are focused more on the morpho-syntactic aspect, e.g. "how do we know 'normalize' is a word as opposed to two words, 'normal' + 'ize'". The question here as I understood it is more of a sociolinguistic one (or maybe just generically Linguistics 101) about how a word enters language. (I'd love to be proven wrong, and this question marked as a duplicate.)

Comment: @jick I don't think "normalize" has exactly the same sense as the one for which Cailyn's new word was going, and I also think there can be stylistic value to a negative construction (e.g. "unhappy") compared to a positive one (e.g. "upset").

Answer (score 8):

The word *deanomalize* follows English word formation rules, and is perfectly fine. Without having encountered this word before, I can understand what it means, and if I use it, other people will also be able to get what I mean.

What makes this a 'proper' word is — as mentioned by others — not a formal process. There is no committee where you can submit your word for it to be accepted. Though in a way there is: the editors of dictionaries have a gatekeeper-like function in that they decide if something is added to a dictionary and thus gets a "seal of approval".

But a word can exist outside of a dictionary. Words spread through usage, and if people find your new word useful (and can understand what it means), and they start using it themselves, then it might eventually become a 'dictionary word'. There are loads of idiosyncratic words, slang words used in small groups, etc. which never spread outside the group, but in a way they are still words.

So if you want to promote your new word, keep using it. Either it will be adopted by other speakers (if there is a genuine need for it), or it will not spread because it is too niche, or there are already other words that express the same meaning.

Answer (score 4):

Language doesn't gain words through some formalized process. Most linguists would say that a string-of-sounds-which-could-potentially-be-a-word (let's call this a pseudo-word for short) is "officially" a word when "enough" people use it to communicate with each other (you know, like most words).

"Enough" is subjective. Some linguists would say you only need one user of a pseudo-word for it to be a word. I think most would agree that if everyone in a small town used a pseudo-word, it's a word (at least in that regional dialect of the language).

As you're probably one of very few people who have ever used the pseudo-word "deanamolize", I would say it's not a word. This doesn't mean you're wrong for saying it, or that you can't use it.

(This doesn't mean that you should continue to use it if someone expresses annoyance with you using it. This isn't coming from a linguistics point of view, but a not-being-obnoxious point of view.)

The way you would "make" it a real word is to normalize its usage, so that "enough" people accept it.

One reason you may find this task difficult is that there's a much more commonly-used word which means something pretty similar, which I used in the previous sentence.

Comment: As a new contributor, I'd appreciate any feedback to the answer, especially if you consider it worthy of a downvote!

Comment: A distilled soundbite version of this process from the film _Mean Girls_: "Gretchen, stop trying to make _fetch_ happen! It's not going to happen!"

Comment: @Michaelyus To the extent that, at least on the Internet, apart from its original meaning, _fetch_ now has the additional meaning ‘something that’s not going to happen no matter how hard you try to make it’. I didn’t even know it originally came from _Mean Girls_, which I’ve never seen – I knew it was a pop culture reference, but not to what specifically.